# selenium exception error in random executions

Tags: python, selenium

i've written the below lines of code:

```
elem = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='drop__expand']")
for i in elem:
  i.click()
```

and i get the below error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element <span class="drop__expand"> is not clickable at point (112,20) because another element <div class="wrapper"> obscures it
```

i tried that without any result:

```
driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='wrapper']").click()
elem = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='drop__expand']")
for i in elem:
   i.click()
```

how can i handle this?

Comment: don't you get error when you run second code? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: if you want to click object then you have to get single object - but `find_elements()` always gives list of objects - even if it finds one element - and you have to use `[0]` to get first element from list before you click it - `driver.find_elements(...)[0].click()`. OR you have to use `find_element()` without `s` at the end to get only first element without using list.

Comment: wrapper doesn't have to be clickable - it may need to remove element from HTML. Or you may try to use javascript to click it  - something like this `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", i)`

Comment: @furas Possibly OP is trying to click on multiple expand elements/buttons in a loop and during the second/third/forth iteration the click is intercepted by a banner/wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

There are two functions:

- `find_elements()` with `s` at the end - to get list with all matching elements - even if there is one element or there is no elements.
- `find_element()` without `s` at the end - to get only first matching elements.

So to click element you may need second function (without `s`)

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='wrapper']").click()
```

or you have to get first element from list when you use first function (with `s`)

```
driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='wrapper']")[0].click()
```

or use `for`-loop

```
for item in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='wrapper']"):
    item.click()
```

---

But wrapper may not be clickable - if it is some popup message then you may need to find button on this wrapper. But you didn't show URL for this page so only you have access to full HTML to check if it has button and find xpath for this button. And here I can't help.

---

You may also try to use JavaScript to click hiddent element(s) and maybe it will work.

Something like this

```
elem = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='drop__expand']")
for i in elem:
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", i)
```

But all this is only guess because you didn't show url for this page and we can't test it.